# How should I add labels in batches using py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am creating a lot of nodes in neo4j using python's py2neo. I am using neo4j version 2 which has support for labels. 
I would like to add a label to the node I have created in batches. Is there a way to do that ?

```
a = batch.create(node(name='Alice'))
```

Now I would like to add the labels "Female", and "Human" to a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already possible to add labels within batches. Have a look in the docs here:

http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/batches/#py2neo.neo4j.WriteBatch.add_labels

Comment: Thanks @Nigel.. dunno how I missed it

Comment: This is a very old post, the batch functionality is no longer available. You'll probably want to look at transactions instead (https://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph.begin).